# How I get ALL keys in Redis? 1+ billion keys in total

Tags: python, redis, key, sortedset

1+ billion keys in redis.
Now I want get **ALL** the keys in python.

```
partkeys = redisclient.keys("abcd*")
```

will be ok.
But

```
keys = redisclient.keys("ab*")
```

will raise ResponseError.

> redis.exceptions.ResponseError: keys err

And

```
keys = redisclient.keys("*")
```

will raise a ConnectionError.
redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error 111 connecting demo.abcd.com:6397. Connection refused.

Any help?

Comment: What version of redis are you using? If it is >= 2.8 try the `scan_iter()` method.

Comment: i didn't get the version of redis. But instances of Redis and StrictRedis haven't scan_iter() method.

Comment: KEYS is a dangerous command - it blocks all other operations while running and, depending on the dataset, could consume a lot of RAM. The connection errors you're getting are because of that. You'll have to "split" your keyspace to little chunks like in your first example and process each one independently... Or upgrade to 2.8+ and use SCAN.

Comment: Or just parse the dump rdb with... a parser written in python:https://github.com/sripathikrishnan/redis-rdb-tools

Answer (score 4):

Use then [**SCAN**](http://redis.io/commands/scan) command to loop over your key set. Using KEYS is always a bad idea. Note that SCAN is only available since Redis 2.8.0.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you use *py-redis*, use `scan_iter`, then:

```
for k in redisclient.scan_iter(match='*'):
     # Do something with k
     # ...
```

As others noted, **SCAN** is only available since Redis 2.8.0